# R wilcox test result conflict

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, p-value

I have gotten R Wilcox test results I do not understand. Comparing two non-Normal independent sets of ~500 ages. The p-value ~.17 but results is "alternative hypothesis: true location shift is not equal to 0". I suspect I must be missing something.

Comment: It's just telling you what the alternative hypothesis *is*. That part has nothing to do with whether you reject the null.

Comment: Thank you very much Glen. Sincerely, Arch